# React checkbox value not changing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-frontend

I'm using `materil-ui` Checkbox but it's not working.

```
    const initialValues = {
        // other values
        isActive: true,
    };


    const NewUser = () => {

        const [values, setValues] = React.useState(initialValues);
    
        const handleInput = (e) =>{
            
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        setValues({ ...values, [name]:value });
        console.log(value)


        return (
            <form>
                <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
                    {/* other form controls */}

                <Checkbox
                    value={values.isActive}
                    name="isActive"
                    label="Is the Employee Active?"
                    onChange={handleInput}
                />
            </form>
        )
    }
    
    export default NewUser;
```

I tried putting it in a separate component so I can handle it separately like this:

```
    export const CheckBoxField =(props) =>{
        const { name, label, value, onChange }= props;
        const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(true);
        const handleChange = (event) => {
            setChecked({ ...checked, [event.target.name]: event.target.checked });
        };
    
        const convertPara = (name, value)=>({
            target:{
                name, value
            }
            
        });

    
        return (
        <>
            <FormControl>
            <FormControlLabel
                label={label}
                control={
                    <Checkbox
                        checked={value}
                        name={name}
                        color="primary"
                        onChange={event => onChange(convertPara(name, event.target.checked))}
                    />
                }
             />
            </FormControl>
        </>
        );
    };
```

All the other controls work fine just the checkbox is not working.
In the console, the value of the checkbox stays the same while it still checks and unchecks. Is the value being `re-rendered` or something, I'm a bit confused here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to let you know, checkbox doesnt have a value, it has property called "checked=TRUE/FALSE"

https://material-ui.com/components/checkboxes/

So in your case.

```
               <Checkbox
                    checked={values.isActive}
                    name="isActive"
                    label="Is the Employee Active?"
                    onChange={handleInput}
                />
```

Make sure, that you `onChange` actually sets it to either TRUE or FALSE :) It should work.

Cheers!

---

EDIT WITH EXAMPLE

Please check below the URL with the codesanbox. I have made both components the one u extracted and the inital one, to display the data, and log it out.

https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-heyrovsky-30mzi?file=/src/App.js:713-719

The code for NewUser component, as you have provided, I have updated it:

```
const initialValues = {
        // other values
        isActive: true,
    };

 const NewUser = () => {

        const [values, setValues] = useState(initialValues);
    
        function handleCheckbox(event){
          setValues({...values, [event.target.name]:event.target.checked})
        }
        console.log("THIS IS FROM INITIAL FROM FIRST TIME ASKED" ,values.isActive)


        return (<>
                <Checkbox
                    checked={values.isActive}
                    name="isActive"
                    label="Is the Employee Active?"
                    onChange={handleCheckbox}
                />
                </>
        )
    }
```

This is initial checkbox, the value is received from `values.isActive`
[image: Initial setup, based on the isActive value set to true.]

---

This is after pressing on the checkbox. The updated value is visible in the `console.log`
[image: This is after pressing on the checkbox the updated value is displayed in the console]

Comment: Tried that @Sarunas

Comment: So, based on your extracted component that you provided, there are a few errors I noticed. With the state of checked, as you initialize it to a boolean, and then try to set it as object, the onChange doesnt work as it is intended, and the neccessity of the converPara still escapes me.

I tried to redo your component for the checkbox, it shows when it is checked/ uncheked in console. please find it here : https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-heyrovsky-30mzi?file=/src/App.js

Comment: What worked is the used of convertPara but you have gone out to help and I say thank you.